# Is this Munkres' proof rigorous? If not, please show me a rigorous proof.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

Is this Munkres' proof of Corollary 10.5 rigorous?
If not, please show me a rigorous proof.
I think Munkres' proof is an intuitive proof.
I think Munkres uses 2-dimensional figure to prove n-dimensional case.

Comment: yes it's rigorous. Why do you think it's not ?

Comment: The $2$-dimensional figure is drawn to show the reader what's going on with the words.  The argument is quite rigorous and is not dependent on the figure.

Comment: @Surb In my head, "rigorous" was equal to "every step is justified by detail". But I was wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin In my head, "rigorous" was equal to "every step is justified by detail". But I was wrong. The 2-dimensional figure helps us to find how to prove n-dimensional case. I love Professor Shifrin's video lectures on YouTube and the blue book about multivariable mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are deceptively simple theorems that are difficult, e.g., Jordan curve theorem, or just tedious to prove.   Because every step is not justified in detail does not mean the proof is not rigorous.

Munkres has outlined the steps to prove a seemingly self-evident corollary that the volume of a rectangle is no greater than the sum of volumes of rectangles in a finite cover. That this even is explicitly stated as a corollary speaks to the level of detail that appears in this book -- in contrast to other books on this subject.

A good exercise would be to fill in the details.  Even the first step -- choose a rectangle $Q'$ containing all rectangles $Q_1,Q_2,\ldots, Q_k$ -- requires justification to be completely (and perhaps excessively) thorough.  Supplying the details here should help you do the same for the remainder of the proof.

In this regard, let $Q_j = [a_{j1},b_{j1}] \times \ldots \times [a_{jn},b_{jn}]$ for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant k$, and define

$$\alpha_p = \min_{1 \leqslant j \leqslant k} a_{jp},\quad \beta_p = \max_{1 \leqslant j \leqslant k} b_{jp}, \quad Q' = [\alpha_1,\beta_1] \times \ldots \times [\alpha_n, \beta_n]$$

If $(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \in Q_j$, then $\alpha_p \leqslant a_{jp} \leqslant x_p \leqslant b_{jp} \leqslant \beta_p$, and consequently $x_p \in [\alpha_p, \beta_p]$ for all $1 \leqslant p \leqslant n$. This, of course, implies that $Q_j \subset Q'$ for all $1 \leqslant j \leqslant k$.

Proceed now to the next step -- use the endpoints of the component intervals of the rectangles $Q, Q_1, \ldots, Q_k$ to define a partition $P$ of $Q'$, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, RRL. In my head, "rigorous" was equal to "every step is justified by detail". But I was wrong.